# Fantasy book that has a giant in a dungeon who gets blinded by creatures with corkscrews for hands

Tags: story-identification, books

I feel like I’ve made it up at this point as I’ve searched for years and never found it but I remember being terrified as a kid.

From what I can remember the main character gets locked in a dungeon and there is a giant who they make friends with but creatures come in the night and try to blind the giant with a sort of corkscrew drill attracted to them. I remember that they made distinct noises that let them know they were there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a kid, so approximately what year would this have been?

Comment: Hi, I’m not sure of my exact age at the time it would have been the early 2000’s when I read it but the book itself could be older

Answer (score 2):

Garth Nix's "Mister Monday", first in the Keys to the Kingdom series. The giant is the Old One, a Prometheus figure chained to a clock in the "Deep Coal Cellar" of the House. Hostile automata emerge from doors in the clock on a regular schedule and blind the Old One.

> The first figure was a caricature of a woodchopper, a little man in
> green with a feather in his cap, no taller than Arthur. He held an ax
> that was almost as big as he was, which chopped up and down haltingly
> as he moved. The second figure was a short fat woman with an apron and
> a frill cap. She held a giant corkscrew, at least two feet long, which
> she held in front of her, turning it with irregular motions as she
> advanced across the clock.

...

> "It is the Old One's punishment. Nothing can be done. They would simply take *your* eyes as well," said Pravuil. "And I do not think yours would regrow with the same facility as the Old One's."